# Is speed better, or is acceleration better?

Tags: forza-motorsport-5

In Forza Motorsport 5, I've recently been racing, and I've got a bit of money in my wallet now. I want to get a good car with these, and I've seen some cars with high speeds but not as good low accelerations.

What I want to know is: what is better/more flexible, speed or acceleration? I know that it really depends, but there should be a certain track that is good for each separate car. So, how can I buy a good car so that the car I buy is flexible to whatever race there is? Sometimes, the more speed isn't the better option, so I just want to be sure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what Car class are you looking to build for? What specific track is giving you trouble? As it stands the question is a bit too broad because in some cases you want speed, others you want accel, others you want to focus on grip/suspension. There's no true "one size fits all". Instead you'll be collecting and tuning many cars and choosing a specific one for each race.

Comment: Not too specific; but really I just want a car that is flexible for most tracks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this is: it depends, specifically, on the layout of the track. I'm providing a universal answer here, not specifically tailored to the quirks of Forza-5 (this applies to most racing games save some very old 8-bit ones that use bit-hacks instead of properly doing accelleration).

**A thought experiment:**

You can simplify how to think about the problem by a simple scenario: a drag race. Suppose two cars, car F and car X hold a drag race.

Car F is the fastest, but car X has better accelleration. To simplify complex physics<sup>1</sup>, we assume the accelleration is constant until top speed is hit. Plugging in some (fake) numbers:

```
Car      Topspeed                Accel        
Car F    100 m/s (360 km/h)      5 m/s^2
Car X    80 m/s  (288 km/h)      8 m/s^2
```

You can solve to get two distance functions:

```
df(t) = 2.5t^2       t <= 20
        100t - 1000  t >= 20
dx(t) = 4t^2         t <= 8
        80t - 400    t >= 8
```

Some basic logic suggests that car X will be passed by car F after both hit top speed `(80 * 20 - 400 = 1200 > 1000)`. Solving for:

```
80t - 400 = 100t - 1000 => t = 30
```

In other words, in 30 seconds, after travelling `30 * 80 = 2400m` car X is overtaken. This means the faster car wins a longer drag race than this, e.g. a 3km race, but would lose a shorter race such as a 2km race.

**How does this translate to a track?**

You might ask, what does a drag race have to do with how such a car performs on a complex twisty track? You can see such a track as a series of straights and turns. You accellerate on the straights, then break just enough to make each turn. This makes each straight section into its own mini-drag race (although with a head start on speed). This then leads to the following rule of thumb:

- On a track with **shorter** straights **accelleration** is more valuable.
- On a track with **longer** straights **top speed** is more important.
- Grip can substitute for accelleration in particular with **sharp** corners and **short** straights (you get more value out of being able to turn at a faster speed the more turns there are).

**Notes**

<sup>1</sup> How complex the physics are will vary from game to game, you'd have to look into its code to figure out how it's handling air resistance and tyre friction for a true comparison. For this higher-order ODE there's no exact solutions, only simulations and approximations.

In a highly realistic racing game air drag will be simulated, and cars have a complex accelleration curve. However, this curve will have a similar shape, so the above points still hold. It's just much harder to calculate when which car comes out ahead.